# I can't install the custom gentoo kernel I just built

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, gentoo

I have built the kernel with this command
`make && make modules_install && make install`.

I am trying to install a custom kernel I just build with this command.
`genkernel --install --kernel-config=.config initramfs`

But it gives me this output:

````
* Using genkernel configuration from '/etc/genkernel.conf' ...
* Running with options: --install --kernel-config=.config initramfs

* Working with Linux kernel 5.15.11-gentoo for x86_64
* Using kernel config file '/usr/src/linux-5.15.11-gentoo/.config' ...

* Current kernel's LOCALVERSION is set to ''; Will ignore set --kernel-localversion value '-x86_64' because kernel was not build ...

* initramfs: >> Initializing ...
*         >> Appending devices cpio data ...
*         >> Appending base_layout cpio data ...
*         >> Appending util-linux cpio data ...
*         >> Appending eudev cpio data ...
*         >> Appending devicemanager cpio data ...
*         >> Appending auxiliary cpio data ...
*         >> Appending busybox cpio data ...
*         >> Appending modprobed cpio data ...
*         >> Appending modules cpio data ...
* ERROR: '/lib/modules/5.15.11-gentoo' does not exist! Did you forget to compile kernel before building initramfs? If you know what you are doing please set '--no-ramdisk-modules'.
* Please consult '/var/log/genkernel.log' for more information and any
* errors that were reported above.
* 
* Report any genkernel bugs to bugs.gentoo.org and
* assign your bug to genkernel@gentoo.org. Please include
* as much information as you can in your bug report; attaching
* '/var/log/genkernel.log' so that your issue can be dealt with effectively.
* 
* Please do *not* report kernel compilation failures as genkernel bugs!```
I don't know how to solve it and there is almost nothing I can find about this online, what should I do?
````

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes I did!

Answer (score 1):

I just put `--no-ramdisk-modules` at the end and that solved it.
This probably isn't the best solution but it worked for me.